# Why is it spelled `#!/usr/bin/env NAME` and not` '#!NAME`

Tags: shebang

Why isn't the default behavior of the shebang line to lookup the first argument as if it was a command? It seems like it is necessary to be a path to a tool.

doesn't work(why?):

```
#!bash
```

works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```